# Diagonalization and $T(f(t))=f(t+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T \colon \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined as $T(f(t))=f(t+1)$. $T$ is diagonalizable? Why?

I know that $1$ is eigenvalue of $T$. I did for case $n=2$. I do not know a way for a general case. I try too, t=0, t=1...

Comment: If $T$ is diagonalizable, then it has a complete set of eigenvalues. Is there any eigenvector other than $f(t) = 1$?

Comment: As @SimonS points out, T will only be diagonalizable if it has a linearly independent set of n+1 eigenvectors. Since 1 is the only eigenvalue, and since the only polynomials satisfying $f(t)=f(t+1)$ are constants, the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is only 1-dimensional; so T is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(f(t))=\lambda f(t)$.

If $\lambda = 0$ else $Tf(t)=0$. On the other hand, $f(t+1)=0$ for all $t$. Therefore, $\lambda$ can not be zero.

If $f(t)=c$ else $Tc=c$. Therefore, $\lambda=1$ is a eigenvalue.

Let $\lambda \neq 0$ and $f(t)=a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_m t^m$ dnt constant (i.e, $a_m \neq 0$). We know that $f(t+1)=\lambda f(t)$. Therefore, $f^{(m)}(t+1)=m!a_m$ is equal to $\lambda f^{(m)}(t)=\lambda m!a_m$. This implies that $\lambda=1$.

Now, we have to $f(t+1)=f(t)$ for all $t$. Contradiction, because does not exist a polynomial of degree $m$ that has this property.

Therefore, we do not have a base formed by eigenvectors implying that the operator is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Although it's hard to tell what you mean at some points, your argument seems fine overall.